# c# xmlarray and xmlarrayitem

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'm trying to use XMLSerializer and have the following code:

```
[XmlArray("ToggleExclusion")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Result")]
    public string[] toCopy { get; set; }
```

And I serialise as such:

```
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));

       StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
       x.Serialize(w, toCopy);
```

However, when the xml is printed, the elements are: typeofstring, and string.

What am I missing here to ensure the elements are as I want above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use XmlRoot for the root item.  It ignores the XmlArray or XmlElement tag for the root.

You may also specify the root name in the XmlSerializer constructor.

Comment: Thanks - that works fine for the root, however the xmlarrayitem tag is still not working as expected?

Comment: If it is at the root, XmlArrayItem may not be used (because it won't be serialized as items under an array).  Try XmlElement.